# How do I check for changes in a database on insert / update?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an interesting problem. I need to write a program that checks to see if data has been inserted or updated into a Microsoft access database . The program needs to be compatible with both types of database, so using triggers is not possible as it wont work in access etc

Anyone out there have any idea as to how to do this check?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You mean have your app check if any other app has made changes to the data in the DB without going through your app?

Comment: yes  marc my app check if any other app has made changes to the data in the DB without going through my app.a message  box is appear some changes in my database specific table

Comment: which are **both** types databases? You mean Access07 vs Access03 and earlier?

Comment: only one database and two applications one i made and other is only exe file if other application  some. changes in database my program appear a message some changes in database

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "both" types of database Access 2010 does have table triggers. And if you use ODBC, c#, automation or even a Access form, in ALL cases the trigger + code runs. IN fact the code runs even in the case where Access has not been installed on the computer in question. (of course the latest edition of the data engine has to be installed however). So just keep in mind that Access 2010 does have table triggers that can run code, and update (or log) updates to a table if you wish. Such code will run if you c#, access form or even using access to edit table direct.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add some fields to your database. Here's what comes to mind:

Add two fields to each table you want to check: `updateTimeAppA` and `updateTimeAppB`. Each app will set its updateTime field to `DateTime.Now` when inserting or updating. Then the app that wants to check whether someone else touched the data can compare the other app's latest update time to its own update time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very large database, it is not difficult ti keep several copies and compare the live version against a copy, it should not take very long.